# jQuery & Angular in Salesforce

Tags: jquery, angular, ui

I am very new to Salesforce development coming from jQuery/Angular framework.

Can I develop UI containing angular/jquery in Salesforce ?.

I am basically trying to learn Salesforce via an approach in which I am very familiar :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can definitely develop UI containing angular/jquery in Salesforce. In fact, that is the current trend. Traditional middleware developers like me who recently moved to salesforce realized that you cant really develop UI with good UX using just visualforce and have to pickup jquery/angular skills for their obvious advantages.

Here is a very helpful introductory [blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2013/06/10/angularjs-and-salesforce-com-tutorial/) that demonstrates very well how angular js could be used in salesforce world.

You might also want to check out the answer to [this question.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27372/feasibility-of-angularjs-in-visualforce-pages)

Answer (score 3):

Why yes you can. I'm the author of the ngForce library, which helps you wrap all kinds of data requests in angular promises!

More here: http://noeticpenguin.github.io/ngForce/

I've built several large apps using it, and angular on visualforce.

Several tricks you can use to. Remember that visualforce is serverside rendered, while angular runs client-side. you can use standard visualforce controllers in conjunction with angular controllers to leverage the best of both worlds!